# C++ - FindFirstChangeNotification sometimes has a large delay

Tags: c++, winapi

i'm implementing a tail-like function. I found that sometimes, i'll get the notification 5 minutes after the file changed.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Change notifications are based on changes to the directory entry. The directory entry for a file being written is not guaranteed to be updated until the handle is closed. Any notifications prior to closure are courtesy and not contractual.

Comment: @Raymond Chen thank you, so if i want to implement a tail-like function. what's the best practice?

Comment: You'll have to poll.  But GetFileSize() should be pretty efficient, provided you keep the file handle open of course, and you'll only need to check, what, maybe ten times a second?  Shouldn't be a problem.